# What is the fastest way to compare the content of two BIG text files in JAVA

Tags: java, performance, text-files

I have two text files that are more than 600MB and I want to compare the content of them if they are the same (Ignoring any space at the end or the start of any line in it i.e. `trim()` each line).
I am thinking of reading each line of them as a string and then trim it and compare it.

Is there is a better idea *and if not* what is the fastest implementation to this idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just need to know if they are the same, or do you need to identify the differences?

Comment: This is going to be a heavy task, there is not much you can do to help that, but what will you do once you know they are the same or not? Will you display the changes? Make sure that you only read through the file once, so that there is no double handling, or wasting of memory. Also you should not read the whole file into memory, process a bit at a time based on your needs, else you could run into an OutOfMemoryError in the future for a larger file.

Comment: @BeUndead No I don't need to identifiy the differences. Just check if they are the same or not

Comment: And can you assume that they are encoded the same (UTF-8, etc.) or do you need to know if the TEXT is the same?

Comment: yes, they are encoded as the same. The files are the outputs of two CPP codes. and what I need is to check if both codes outputs are the same. i.e. the two codes produces the same output or not

Comment: Then just streaming the bytes of both files ([see section 2 here for tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/nio/nio-read-file/)) and breaking on the first difference is probably fast enough.

Comment: With obvious prechecks like ‘are they pointing to the same file’ and ‘are the file sizes the same’.

Comment: Side note: if you’re just using this to quickly compare two output files, and then never look at it again, write the simplest thing and let it run once. That’ll be faster than the additional time spent working out, writing and debugging how to do it the fastest way.

Comment: @BeUndead No this is part of a project I am working on. Its to compare if the two CPP codes generate the same output or not and by the way, check the wrong CPP code.
So I run terminal command in java to compile and run the two cpp files and make the output of the terminal in two text files. Now i need to compare these two output files

Comment: Then yeah. The fastest, pure java way will probably be the ByteBuffer way I linked above, with some complex checks for space and new line characters to handle the trim part. I’ll bow out for anyone else to give an actual answer or better approach.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to compare whether the files are consistent, please calculate the file md5 value to compare：

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath1 = "D:\\Download\\a.mp3";
    String filePath2 = "D:\\Download\\b.mp3";
    String file1_md5 = md5HashCode(filePath1);
    String file2_md5 = md5HashCode(filePath2);

    System.out.println(file1_md5);
    System.out.println(file2_md5);
    if(file1_md5.equals(file2_md5)){
        System.out.println("Two files are the same ");
    }
}

/**
 * get file md5 value
 */
 public static String md5HashCode(String filePath) {
    try {
        InputStream fis =new FileInputStream(filePath);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = -1;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            md.update(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        fis.close();
        byte[] md5Bytes  = md.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5Bytes);
        return bigInt.toString(16);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
     }
  }
}
```

If you need to read each line of the file for comparison：

```
    List<String> file1_lines = null;
    List<String> file2_lines = null;
    try {
        file1_lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:/a.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        file2_lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:/b.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < file1_lines.size(); i++) {
        String file1_line = file1_lines.get(i).trim();
        String file2_line = file2_lines.get(i).trim();
        if (file1_line.equals(file2_line)) {
            //do some
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn’t handle not considering whitespace at the start/end of a line as not being relevant to the comparison.

Comment: This will not trim each line but This is the only fast way to compare BIG files. Thanks.

Comment: I revised my answer

Comment: @BlueFire No, it isn't 'the only fast way to compare big files'. A byte-for-byte comparison after trimming the lines would do just as well, and be at least as fast, and if you stop after the first difference it is far quicker.

Comment: @段小言 The first code compares two files efficiently but without triming the lines.
The second code compares them with triming But kills the efficiency and the memory.

Comment: It will definitely be faster to stop after the first difference. Calculating the MD5 for two big files requires us to read both of them completely. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @user207421 And if i can ignore trimming the lines (i.e. i will change some parts of the program to avoid trimming the lines) 
What will be the fastest way ? The time is most important thing here. Thanks.

Comment: @BlueFire You've been told several times that the fastest way is just to compare bytes and stop when they aren't equal. Make sure to use `BufferedInputStreams`.